# np.subtract.outer() returning more dimensions than I expect

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe that is indexed by date and has four columns, all integers.

My final goal is to make another dataframe, that also indexes by date, and instead of having four columns of scalar values,  is a 4x4 array that has all the combinations of differences between the four columns' values on that date.

```
           A   B    C   D
1/1/2013    7   -1  1   2
```

I would want to make a 2d array that looks like:

```
        A   B   C   D
        7   -1  1   2
A   7   0   8   6   5
B   -1  -8  0   -2  -3
C   1   -6  2   0   -1
D   2   -5  3   1   0
```

where the values of the data are the combinations of the differences between the columns' values.

Then I'd make this 2d array for each date in the original dataframe

I've been trying to do this 'pythonically/panda-ly' without gross loops and things.

I made the simplest case -- the original dataframe has only one row of data:

```
ddf is type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, shape (1, 4)
            A  B  C  D
2013-01-02  7 -1  1  2
```

I feed that ddf into

```
def makeRelativeChangeDF(deltaDF):
    """return array wit all the combinations of differences between columns"""
    return np.subtract.outer(deltaDF, deltaDF)
```

This returns:

```
rcdf is type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, shape (1, 4)
[[[[ 0.  8.  6.  5.]]

  [[-8.  0. -2. -3.]]

  [[-6.  2.  0. -1.]]

  [[-5.  3.  1.  0.]]]]
```

Not sure why this is giving the weird shape (1,4).   I was expecting (4,4).  And looking at the print of the rcdf, i can see it's heavily wrapped in multiple arrays.  I guess I'm incorrectly using the outer function.  I would like to do this the right way than using ugly reshape hacks to pull the (correct) data out but repackage it in a correct shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the 2D input dataframe to a 1D series by selecting the first row with [`.iloc[0]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then use [`np.subtract.outer()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), like so -

```
np.subtract.outer(deltaDF.iloc[0],deltaDF.iloc[0])
```

It seems you can also use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
deltaDF.iloc[0][:,None] - deltaDF.iloc[0][None,:]
```

Sample run -

```
In [107]: type(deltaDF)
Out[107]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [108]: np.subtract.outer(deltaDF.iloc[0],deltaDF.iloc[0])
Out[108]: 
array([[ 0,  8,  6,  5],
       [-8,  0, -2, -3],
       [-6,  2,  0, -1],
       [-5,  3,  1,  0]])

In [109]: deltaDF.iloc[0][:,None] - deltaDF.iloc[0][None,:]
Out[109]: 
array([[ 0,  8,  6,  5],
       [-8,  0, -2, -3],
       [-6,  2,  0, -1],
       [-5,  3,  1,  0]])
```

Comment: Thanks.  A confounding issue is that the 'array' is actually a row from a DataFrame.  ravel() only works on np.array, so I need to figure out how to march through a dataframe and treat each indexed row as a np.array for this. (Asked a separate question for this problem)

Comment: @user3556757 - you could use `.values` to get the data from a row, which in your case is a numpy array.